# Getting ODBC error in MS Access when opening labels in preview mode with SQL Server data source, doesn't happen in report mode

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I am tasked with converting an old MS Access application to a MS Access front end and SQL Server back end. I have several reports (all labels) which are causing a SQL Server ODBC error when I open them in preview mode but which open in report mode.

This command fails:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport Me.cmbReportSelection, acPreview, , whereStr
```

This command works

```
DoCmd.OpenReport Me.cmbReportSelection, acViewReport, , whereStr
```

until I switch to preview mode then it fails with the same error as if I opened it in preview mode.

Error message received:

> Microsoft Access
>   ODBC -- call failed
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]A column has been specified more than once in the order by list. Columns in the order by list must be unique (#169)

- MS Access 2013  (`.accdb` file format)
- SQL Server 2016

I have put enough displays in to determine its not likely the error message is correct unless Access is doing something after I provide the data source, where condition, filter and order properties.   Given that the code works if I open it in acViewReport instead of acPreview, I am not sure its anything I am doing.

The code also seems to work in a version of the database that connects to an MS Access backend and in the original system's .mdb format.

it also doesn't matter if there is a where condition, filter on or order on set.  The open report is being called from a report selection menu that include options for a variety of filter, sort, and group criteria that can be used for a number of reports but its only the 3 reports that are "labels" that seem to have this problem.

The code flow is: from the report selection form, select a report from a pull down,  fill in any desired filter, sort and group criteria, click on a command button to preview the report.

The command button code processed the filter condition options to assemble a where condition for the report "whereStr" variable

The individual report  on-load functions call a common function which handles sort options and a few other things and then the load function takes care of setting the filter and order by properties of the report.

The RecordSource of the reports is a Select Statement.   one example is below

```
SQL
SELECT tblAllFacilities.FacLicenseNumber, tblAllFacilities.FacMedicareNumber, tblAllFacilities.FacName, tblAllFacilities.FacName2, [tblHHA/Hospice Facilities].[Mail Address 1], [tblHHA/Hospice Facilities].[Mail City], tblAllFacilities.FacCity, [tblHHA/Hospice Facilities].[Mail State], [tblHHA/Hospice Facilities].[Mail Zip], tblAllFacilities.FacNotActiveDate, [tblHHA/Hospice Facilities].PhoneNumber, [tblHHA/Hospice Facilities].[Contact Lst Nme], [tblHHA/Hospice Facilities].[Contact Fst Nme], [tblHHA/Hospice Facilities].[Contact Phone], [tblHHA/Hospice Facilities].[Contact Ext], tblAllFacilities.FacAdminName, tblAllFacilities.FacAdminLast, tblAllFacilities.FacAdminTitle, tblAllFacilities.ToBeDeleted, tblAllFacilities.[Facility Type], tblAllFacilities.FacStatusCode
FROM [tblHHA/Hospice Facilities] RIGHT JOIN tblAllFacilities ON [tblHHA/Hospice Facilities].[670FacIDLink] = tblAllFacilities.FacID
WHERE (((tblAllFacilities.FacNotActiveDate) Is Null) AND ((tblAllFacilities.ToBeDeleted)=False) AND ((tblAllFacilities.FacStatusCode)="Active") AND ((tblAllFacilities.FacClosedDate) Is Null));
```

I am expecting the label reports to come up in preview with the correct filter and sort applied.

What I am getting is the ODBC error saying I have a duplicate Order by column unless I change the mode the report is opened in.   Then it works till I switch to preview mode.

SOLVED:
The 3 label reports had sorted defined within the grouping criteria that I did not see nor expect since they were labels.    When I did a trace on the database to see what SQL server was actually receiving, I found that MS Access made 1 call in report view mode and a 2nd in print preview mode.   only the print preview mode included both the grouping criteria and the orderby property.

First select is from going in in report mode and contains the order by specified in the group by part of the report definition
 
SELECT "FacName" ,"FacAdminName" ,"FacAdminLast" ,"FacAdminTitle" ,"FacAddress" ,"FacCity" ,"FacState" ,"FacZip"  FROM "dbo"."tblAllFacilities" WHERE (((("FacNotActiveDate" IS NULL ) AND ("FacClosedDate" IS NULL ) ) AND ("FacStatusCode" = 'Active' ) ) AND ("ToBeDeleted" = 0) ) ORDER BY "dbo"."tblAllFacilities"."FacName" ,"dbo"."tblAllFacilities"."FacName2"
Go
 
The 2nd selection is when I switched from report to preview mode and it made a 2nd call which included both the grouping order on fields and the report orderby field list.
 
SELECT "FacName" ,"FacAdminName" ,"FacAdminLast" ,"FacAdminTitle" ,"FacAddress" ,"FacCity" ,"FacState" ,"FacZip"  FROM "dbo"."tblAllFacilities" WHERE (((("FacNotActiveDate" IS NULL ) AND ("FacClosedDate" IS NULL ) ) AND ("FacStatusCode" = 'Active' ) ) AND ("ToBeDeleted" = 0) ) ORDER BY "dbo"."tblAllFacilities"."FacName" ,"dbo"."tblAllFacilities"."FacName2" ,"dbo"."tblAllFacilities"."FacName"
go
 
interesting that it re-queried the database switching from report view to print preview mode.

Comment: Not sure what isn't clear about that error message. You have the same column name being returned in your result set for at least two different columns, AND that column is part of the order by. You can't do that.

Comment: AFAIK, correct parameter is `acViewPreview`. Although if error occurs with manually opening report, then must not be cause of issue.

Comment: Report View and Print Preview are two different document formatting states. The error is exactly what it says it is, you just haven't found it yet. Could be in your Events, your vba, the Data Tab of the Report's Properties, duplicate columns in your source query, sorting on both an alias and the original name, or a combination of any of these elements. Either way, it's trying to do the same thing, to what it thinks is the same field, twice.

Comment: Please note,  I have checked, rechecked and tested all the parameters, data and code and I do not believe the error message is accurate as the exact same select works fine in a query or when given directly to SSMS.

Comment: Further info:  I have further determined that sometime Access will crash completely after clicking on ok and other times will not.   I have also determined that only "label" reports which use a SELECT as the data source are impacted.   It does not matter if there is any ORDER by condition set or not.  It occurs even when there is no filter or order by property set.

Comment: Further info 2:   converting the select to a query and using that as the data source also does not work although the query runs fine independently but when used as the report data source, I get the same errors.      Trying this is Access Office 365 also generates the same error and crashes following responding to the error prompt.

Comment: SOLVED:  a combination of grouping criteria doing sorts and Access generating different SQL statements in report and print preview mode.